# Javascript iterate over array of hash and get keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have build my own application using NodeJs with MySQL database. When I fetch a table I am getting some set of value which will look like this. My actual requirement is I need to get keys of hashes from this array.

```
 [ RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'aoc_com', Input: 'ipc3' },
  RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'build', Input: 'RH' },
  RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'daq_type', Input: 'Full' },
  RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'endingport', Input: '8030' },
  RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'id_type', Input: 'TAM9' },
  RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'od_build_type', Input: 'Test_OD' },
```

First I tried to remove `RowDataPacket` by using JSON.stringify(rows). Now my array look like this

```
[{"FieldName":"aoc_com","Input":"ipc3"},{"FieldName":"build","Input":"RH"},{"FieldName":"daq_type","Input":"Full"},{"FieldName":"endingport","Input":"8030"},{"FieldName":"id_type","Input":"TAM9"},{"FieldName":"od_build_type","Input":"Test_OD"}]
```

Then I store this output in a variable as `sysConValues` and then when I tried to iterate over the var `sysConValues`

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
  for (var key in sysConValues[i]) { 
     console.log(sysConValues); 
  }
}
```

I'm getting output as 0 instead of `['FieldName', 'Input']`. What I did wrong here and how to get keys from `sysConValues`.

Comment: `for (var key of Object.keys(sysConValues[i])) {`

Comment: As you have `JSON.stringify(rows)` you need to `JSON.parse()` it in order to iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did understand by your question is that you want keys for every object in your array.

So you can get keys by using `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
let arr = [{
    FieldName: 'aoc_com',
    Input: 'ipc3'
  },
  {
    FieldName: 'build',
    Input: 'RH'
  },
  {
    FieldName: 'daq_type',
    Input: 'Full'
  },
  {
    FieldName: 'endingport',
    Input: '8030'
  },
  {
    FieldName: 'id_type',
    Input: 'TAM9'
  },
  {
    FieldName: 'od_build_type',
    Input: 'Test_OD'
  }
];

let keyArr = arr.map(o => Object.keys(o));
console.log(keyArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to remove `RowDataPacket`, by using `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`. You can leave it as is and iterate over the original array.

```
var packets = [ RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'aoc_com', Input: 'ipc3' },
    RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'build', Input: 'RH' },
    RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'daq_type', Input: 'Full' },
    RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'endingport', Input: '8030' },
    RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'id_type', Input: 'TAM9' },
    RowDataPacket { FieldName: 'od_build_type', Input: 'Test_OD' }];

packets.forEach(function (packet) {
    for(var key in packet) {
        if(!packet.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }

        console.log(key);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I iterate this same inside .ejs

Comment: Yes, but it's a better practice to encapsulate this into a function.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer to your question**

```
var array = [{"FieldName":"aoc_com","Input":"ipc3"}, 
  {"FieldName":"build","Input":"RH"}, 
  {"FieldName":"daq_type","Input":"Full"}, 
  {"FieldName":"endingport","Input":"8030"}, 
  {"FieldName":"id_type","Input":"TAM9"}, 
  {"FieldName":"od_build_type","Input":"Test_OD"}];
var hashResult = {};
for (var key in array) { 
  console.log(array[key].FieldName); 
  hashResult[`${array[key].FieldName}`] = array[key].Input;
}

console.log(hashResult);
```

Comment: thanks for your response but here keys will get change of all the tables. So we should not use the keys static.

Comment: can you brief on keys static.

Comment: Static means hard code something like that. Sorry I were wrong.